# Open SharePoint 2010 list item via custom web part

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepointdocumentlibrary

On my SharePoint 2010 site I have a list of items (Document Library). This library contains xml files.

Also, I have a Visual Web Part which displays data from these xml files.

Is there a way to somehow *bind* the web part to this document library so that the items will be opened *via* the web part?

*Note:
At this point the list item has a hyperlink field which points to the web part page and provides the location of xml file as query string. When the link is accessed, the web part gets provided xml data and parses it as it should.

The problem with this approach is that an absolute url is saved in item's field, which will result into problems when server is changed.*

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the Sharepoint 2010 "Related List" feature. Sharepoint 2010 allows to send and receive data between webparts, so even your custom webpart.

See the following link for a how-to: [SP 2010: How To - Relational lists in SharePoint 2010](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/01/05/sp-2010-how-to-relational-lists-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Finally I arrived to the series of articles on "sharepoint web part connections" and found out that two web parts communicate via a specific interface. In my case, my web part used IWebPartField interface through which a List View Web Part exposes a row's field - exactly what I needed.

Comment: Sounds very good paschka, good luck with your further endeavors. When you consider the answer as helpful consider marking it with a checkmark.